# Why an ajax query is called twice

Tags: django, ajax

I try to update database using ajax query

I get row table id on click to send to view for updating data

but as my ajax is called twice (why?), second call reverse first call

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            {% for dcf in datacorrections %}
            <tr>
                <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">{{ dcf.ide }}</td>
                <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" id="{{ dcf.ide }}">{{ dcf.deativated }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

```
    $('body').on('click','td', function() {
        var _id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{% url 'monitoring:deactivate_dcf' %}",
                data: { "id" : _id },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (response) {
                    obj = JSON.parse(response);
                },

            });
    });
```

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def deactivate_dcf(request):
    
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        datacorrection_id = request.POST.get("id")

        if DataCorrection.objects.filter(ide = datacorrection_id).exists():
           
            if DataCorrection.objects.get(ide = datacorrection_id).deativated == False:
                DataCorrection.objects.filter(ide = datacorrection_id).update(deativated=True)
            else:
                DataCorrection.objects.filter(ide = datacorrection_id).update(deativated=False)

            return JsonResponse({"response": "success",}, status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"response": "failed","exist":"datacorrection not exist"}, status=404)

    return JsonResponse({"response":"not_ajax"}, status=200)
```

Comment: try unbind then bind the click event using @Drayen solution  $(".clickable-td").unbind("click").click(function(){//your code});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class "clickable-td" to the clickable td:

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" class="clickable-td" data-placement="top" title="" id="{{ dcf.ide }}">{{ dcf.deativated }}</td>
```

add this instead, it will trigger the event on this td and it should stop the propagation.

```
$('.clickable-td').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var _id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(_id);
    $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'monitoring:deactivate_dcf' %}",
            data: { "id" : _id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("we went throught !");
                console.log(response);
            },

        })
});
```

If you go in the console inspector and find the console log of the ID then it should be fine.

Comment: still the same problem; ajax is called twice

Comment: try the edit, the method is post not type is post and dataType is json,

Comment: copy paste the jquery code I edited and if it works upvote it ^^